# Are there any god machine experience conversion rules for Werewolf?

Tags: house-rules, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, werewolf-the-forsaken

In lieu of an update book has anyone suggested, or does anyone have suggestions for experience conversion rates for Gifts, Rituals, and Rites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some fan-made rules here: [Onyx Path Forums](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/werewolf-the-forsaken/27026-stopgap-werewolf-the-forsaken-gmc-conversion). Official values will come in *The Idigam Chronicle*; they've already stated that [Harmony won't be purchasable.](http://theonyxpath.com/one-foot-in-flesh-and-one-in-spirit/) There's more info on the conversion in the blog in the last link.

A brief summary: The same costs as in Blood and Smoke, basically.

> ### Experience
>
> - Attribute: 4 Experiences per dot
> - Merit: 1 Experience per dot
> - Totem: 1 Experience per dot
> - Skill Specialty: 1 Experience
> - Skill: 2 Experiences per dot
> - Affinity Gift: 3 Experiences per gift
> - Other Gift: 4 Experiences per gift
> - Primary Renown: 4 Experiences per dot
> - Other Renown: 5 Experiences per dot
> - Harmony: 3 Experiences per dot
> - Primal Urge: 5 Experiences per dot
> - Rites: 1 Experience per dot
> - Willpower: 1 Experience per dot

Comment: what about rituals? honestly I'm just coming back up to speed on werewolf, so I'm not sure on the relationship of rituals to other things... will probably take the time to read on that later...

Comment: also apparently the Iratheur (Spirit masters) get rites at half cost, would this mean other auspices should get them at 2xp or that iratheur should get 2 dots for every 1xp, or will this just cease to matter.

Comment: I don't know much about Forsaken, but I think rites are rituals. If Iratheur get rites at half cost, then they would get 2 dots for every 1 Experience. Since costs are flat in GMC, not graduated, that works out fine.